# ServiceStack: Keep getting HTTP 500 errors for unknown reason

Tags: servicestack, http-error

All of a sudden, I keep getting HTTP 500 errors in my self-hosted ServiceStack WS.

I have several requests already in place and they are working fine, but this one just wont work. I have added my license like this:

```
    private void StartServiceStackService()
    {
        Licensing.RegisterLicenseFromFileIfExists("servicestack-license.txt".MapHostAbsolutePath());

        _serviceStackHost = new ServiceStackWsHost(this, _frontEndModuleParameters, _alfaWebServicesSettings);
        _serviceStackHost.Init();
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            _serviceStackHost.Start(new[] { "http://+:8080/" });
        }
        else
        {
            _serviceStackHost.Start(new[] { "http://+:8081/" });
        }
    }
```

And the failing service is:

```
[Route(Bookings.BASE_PATH + "search", Verbs = "GET")]
public class SearchAddress : IReturn<SearchAddressResponse>
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
}

public class SearchAddressResponse : ResponseBase
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    // public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

internal class SearchAddressHandler : ServiceHandlerBase
{
    public SearchAddressResponse Get(SearchAddress searchAddress)
    {
        return new SearchAddressResponse()
        {
            Test = "ASDASDASD"
        };
    }
}
```

[image]

And I call it using Fiddler4 like this:

```
GET http://192.168.0.147:8081/alfaonline/bookings/search?SearchString=123 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: 192.168.0.147:8081
AuthToken: a18b613c-23b2-4f4e-8934-ad8d6cbc57bb
DeviceUUID: 1baaace
```

and get this reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5.20 Net45/Windows
Date: Wed, 26 Sep 2018 11:28:31 GMT

0
```

If I instead return "null", like this:

```
[MyAuthenticate]
internal class SearchAddressHandler : ServiceHandlerBase
{
    public SearchAddressResponse Get(SearchAddress searchAddress)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Fiddler gives me HTTP 204 OK:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 OK
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5.20 Net45/Windows
Date: Wed, 26 Sep 2018 11:26:29 GMT
```

I see no errors, exceptions in VS in debug mode and "catch all" in Exception settings. I can put a breakpoint in the handler, and it breaks there, so the correct handler is executed.

---

**UPDATE** I have always been using Fiddler, now running Fiddler4. When I try the service, described below, in for example swagger (plugin to ServiceStack), it runs as expected. If I run the service in Postman, it runs as expected. But if I run it in Fiddler, I get HTTP 500

---

**UPDATE 2** I also just noticed that going to http://127.0.0.1:8081/requestlogs also yields HTTP 500 error. More specifically, when I access /requestlogs and add the UncaughtExceptionHandlers, I see this error:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String
>   ServiceStack.StringUtils.HtmlEncodeLite(System.String)'.    at
>   ServiceStack.Formats.HtmlFormat.d__10.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&
>   stateMachine)    at
>   ServiceStack.Formats.HtmlFormat.SerializeToStreamAsync(IRequest req,
>   Object response, Stream outputStream)    at
>   ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: Made two updates, where both are interesting. http://127.0.0.1:8081/requestlogs doesnt work anymore, HTTp 500 there too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach should be to get information about the Error:

- Include a `ResponseStatus` property in your Response DTO if not already,
- Enable [Config.DebugMode](http://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#debugmode)
- Add [Debug Logging](http://docs.servicestack.net/logging#built-in-loggers)
- Register [Exception Handlers](http://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#register-handlers-for-handling-service-exceptions).

Comment: I have or course read the docs before posting =) I am using your preferred structure, message-based, DTOs etc, so ResponseStatus is there, but I get nothing of that in return from Fiddler. Since I run in debug mode, DebugMode should be enabled per default? I have added `StrictMode = true` now, but I still see nothing of value in console or elsewhere (I added `LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory(debugEnabled: true);`). I see `DEBUG: CreateRequestAsync/requestParams:SearchString` as a log, but still 500 in Fiddler, but not in Postman...

Comment: I added *Update 2* above: http://127.0.0.1:8081/requestlogs doesnt work, I get HTTP 500 there too.

Comment: After adding `UncaughtExceptionHandlers` I see some stuff though: `Error: MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String ServiceStack.StringUtils.HtmlEncodeLite(System.String)'.` when trying to access the `/requestslogs`

Comment: ? MissingMethodException? =)

Comment: You have dirty dlls, ensure all NuGet packages use the same version, delete the packages bin and obj folders than restore packages again.

Comment: I removed obj and bin folders, cleard nuget cache, restored NuGet packages, rebuilt solution, launched and tried to access requestlogs again - and now it works to access `/requestlogs` again. Thx, dunno what happened, but you obviouslt seen it before? =)

Comment: @Ted MissingMethodException is due to trying to call a method that does not exist, the primary cause of which is that it’s using a different .dll than what the library was compiled with. The solution being to clean the solution and ensure all packages use the same version.